# How can I specify the port number with DBD::ODBC?

Tags: perl, odbc, dsn

I currently use the following code to connect to a database in my Perl script:

```
my $dsn = 'dbi:ODBC:MYDATABASE';
my $database = 'uat_env';
my $user = 'user';
my $auth = 'password';

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $auth, {
    RaiseError => 1,
    AutoCommit => 1
}) or die("Couldn't connect to database");

$dbh->do('use '.$database);
```

Now the port has changed from 1433 to 40450.

I am having trouble changing the port in the DSN. I thought this change would work but I am receiving a "DSN not found" error:

```
my $dsn = 'dbi:ODBC:MYDATABASE;Port=40450';
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: What is the underlying database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two formats for a DBI data source string for ODBC. You can say either

```
dbi:ODBC:DSN=MYDATABASE
```

or you can abbreviate that to

```
dbi:ODBC:MYDATABASE
```

which is what you have. If you use *just* the DSN then you can't add any more parameters, so your `dbi:ODBC:MYDATABASE;Port=40450` is looking for DSN `MYDATABASE;Port=40450` which clearly doesn't exist

The proper way to do this is to set up a new DSN which has a copy of all the parameters of `MYDATABASE`, but with a different port name

At a *guess*, I would say you may be able to write

```
dbi:ODBC:DSN=MYDATABASE;Port=40450
```

but I can't be sure and I have no way of testing

If your requirements are simple then you can supply all of the parameters instead of a DSN, like this

```
dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};Server=11.22.33.44;Port=40450
```

but you will have to supply the correct driver if you aren't using a SQL Server ODBC connection, and other parameters may be necessary

You should start by examining the values in the `MYDATABASE` DSN and go from there

Comment: Thank you so much! dbi:ODBC:DSN=MYDATABASE;Port=40450 worked. I didn't know that I had to add DSN= for it to pick up the parameters. Have been banging my head over this all day.